# possible to get sandboxes on partner portal dev org?

Tags: partner-portal

I provisioned an Enterprise Edition org from the Partner Portal which does have sandboxes. However it says I can only create unmananaged packages.

The Partner Portal Dev Org I have doesn't have any sandboxes.

Is there a way to provision one that has sandboxes and allows the creation of managed packages?

Answer (score 3):

You can only create Managed Packages from within a Dev Org.

Sign up for one at http://developer.salesforce.com/

---

You can create *unManaged* packages in any type of Salesforce org (Production, Sandbox, Dev) which may be what you're looking for.  Managed Packages are only required if you want to make an App-Exchange App.

If you are just looking to communicate between your Sandbox and Production (say deploy an `Apex Class` and associated test `Apex Class` and a `Visualforce Page`), I strongly recommend you use **Change Sets** since they are easy to use.  There is also another option of using the Force.com IDE for Eclipse for intermediate-advanced users.

Comment: What I'm really asking is how can I create both managed packages and have a sandbox with a Partner Portal Org.

Comment: Those are two different types of things.  (1) If you want to create Managed Packages, you can only do that in a Dev Org, and Dev Orgs are free (and you can have as many as you desire).  (2) Every paid Salesforce org has at least one Sandbox (you can always pay for more...), and that Sandbox is Linked SOLELY with the paid Production org.

Comment: And Dev orgs cannot have sandboxes.